# Headless script crashes after a few runs

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cron, selenium-firefoxdriver, pyvirtualdisplay

I have a script using a headless browser which I'm running using `crontab -e`.  It runs fine the first few times and then crashes with the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/clint-selenium-firefox.py", line 83, in <module>
    driver.get(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
```

My crontab line is:

```
*/10 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && python /home/clint-selenium-firefox.py >> /home/error.log 2>&1
```

I don't want to overload this with the python script so I've pulled out what I think are the relevant bits.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
...
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
...
driver.quit()
...
display.stop()
```

Your help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Versions: Firefox 49.0.2;  Selenium : 3.0.1;  geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.11.1-linux64.tar.gz

Code around error (failing on `driver.get(url)`):

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
if DEBUG: print "Opened Firefox"

for u in urls:
    list_of_rows = []
    list_of_old_rows = []

    # get the old version of the site data
    mycsvfile = u[1]
    try:
        with open(mycsvfile, 'r') as csvfile:
            old_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
            for o in old_data:
                list_of_old_rows.append(o)
    except: pass

    # get the new data
    url = u[0]
    if DEBUG: print url    

    driver.get(url)
    if DEBUG: print driver.title
    time.sleep(1)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
```

Comment: I've been doing alot or reading about this.  Do I need to use Marionette?

Comment: what are firefox, selenium and geckodriver versions that you are using?

Comment: In each case I'm downloading the latest version

Comment: I got the point but I need version names for confirmation :). Also, share the python code of the method which contains line 83 in clint-selenium-firefox.py

Comment: @Naveen I've added info as requested

Comment: ok. try the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40208762.

Comment: What exactly am I trying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128375/discussion-between-naveen-and-henrym).

Comment: can you join the chat link shared in above link?

Comment: Firefox isn't headless.  Are you using [Xvfb](http://tobyho.com/2015/01/09/headless-browser-testing-xvfb/)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Xvfb

Comment: Sorry, no, I'm using `pyvirtualdisplay` which I understand mimics it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Multiple Firefox instances failing with NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE #99](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/99) *This is because no --marionette-port option is passed to geckodriver - which means all instances of geckodriver launch firefox passing the same desired default port (2828). The first firefox instance binds to that port, future instances can't and all the geckodriver instances end up connecting to the first firefox instance - which produces all sorts of unpredictable behavior.*

Followed by: *I think a reasonable short-term solution is to do what the other drivers are doing and ask Marionette to bind to a randomised, free port generated by geckodriver. Currently it uses 2828 as the default for all instances it spawns of Firefox.
Since Marionette unfortunately does not yet have an out-of-band way of communicating the port back to the client (geckodriver), this is inherently racy but we can improve the situation in the future with one of the proposals from bug 1240830.*

This [change](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/CHANGES) was made in

```
Selenium 3.0.0.b2
* Updated Marionette port argument to match other drivers.
```

I guess random only works for so long. Raise an [issue](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues). A code fix may be required for the versions of selenium, firefox and geckodriver that you have.  You could drop back to using Selenium 2.53.0 and firefox esr 38.8 until this is fixed.  Your call.

UPDATE: Try

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('path/to/binary')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Comment: I'm trying to go back to earlier versions.  Installing Selenium 2.53.0 was easy but I'm struggling to get firefox esr 38.8.  I'm trying `sudo apt-get install iceweasel` and it is simply selecting and installing the latest version of firefox.  Could you advice how to force the older version.

Comment: I've managed to go back to the versions you've proposed but I now get `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Comment: On linux, I opened my google chrome browser and typed  https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-38.8.0esr-SSL&os=linux&lang=ach

Comment: You get the error doing what? Please provide some context.

Comment: You need to make sure that you completely uninstall the old firefox before installing the esr release. I run two different firefoxes myself but you have to be careful how you do it.

Comment: I've installed firefox in a separate directory and I'm calling it using `driver=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=path/to/binary)` and when I run my script I'm getting the OSError stated above

Comment: sudo chown -R $USER /path/to/binary

Comment: Change that to sudo chown 775 $USER /path/to/binary

Comment: See the update I made above. Firefox wants to pull the path to the binary from your PATH.  Worse case, change your PATH environment variable to point to the new binary's directory path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128755/discussion-between-mikejramsey56-and-henrym).

Comment: Got it, I was just directing to the directory rather than the binary. Sorted now and working.  Thank you